# New Fig Tree Leaves Dying

Tags: leaves, diseases, fruit-trees, fungus, figs

Our fig trees budded and new leaves emerged, but after about a week the edges turned brown and the leaves have curled up and died. Only two leaves are left on one of the trees, though new buds are starting.

I'm leaning toward it being a fungus, but my understanding is "fig rust" affects the whole leaf rather than just starting at the edge. Any ideas what's going on and how I can combat this?

Location is northeastern United States.

[image: Dead fig tree leaves]

Comment: where is the tree growing?  What part of the world?

Comment: @kevinskio location added